# Create Path Between Initial Child Nodes - D3 Tree Layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using the [D3 Collapsible Tree Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) and would like to create a path that begins at the first child node and travels all the way to the last initial child node, while mainlining it's position when the graph is scaled/updated. Basically this is what I'm going for

[image]

I've tried this so far:

```
var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();
/**
  * transition logic, etc
**/
var rootNodes = [ nodes[0], nodes[1] ]; //will use first 2 nodes as an example (will want to include all initial root nodes)
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line('step')
    .x(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .interpolate("linear");
var lineGraph = vis.append("path")
    .attr("d", lineFunction(nodes))
    .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1.5")
    .attr("fill", "none");

    }
```

However I'm not sure how to get it to transition within the update() function properly, also it creates extra paths under the root nodes and ends up looking like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** If I grab the `root` of my data array, I can keep my new paths within the first child nodes of my tree

```
root = json;//JSON Object returned from my program
//...
var rootNodes = [ root.children[0], root.children[1] ];
```